# Plot grouped barplot with absolute and percent values + labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am quite new to R and especially to ggplot. For my next result I think I have to change from `plot()` to `ggplot()` where I need your help:

I have a dataframe with numeric values. One column is an absolute number, the other one is the belonging percentage value. I have 3 of this "two groups" indicators a, b and c.
The rownames are the 6 observations and are stored in the first column "X".
I want to plot them in a kind of grouped barplot, where the absolute+percent column is next to each other for the 3 indicators.

Sample dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(X = c("e 1","e 1,5","e 2","e 2,5","e 3","e 3,5","e 4"),
            a_abs=c(-0.3693,-0.0735,-0.019,0.0015,0,-0.0224,-0.0135),
            a_per=c(-0.4736,-0.0943,-0.0244,0.0019,0,-0.0287,-0.0173),
            b_abs=c(-0.384,-0.0733,-0.0173,0.0034,0,-0.0204,-0.0179),
            b_per=c(-0.546,-0.1042,-0.0246,0.0048,0,-0.029,-0.0255),
            c_abs=c(-0.3876,-0.0738,-0.019,0.0015,0,-0.0225,-0.0137),
            c_per=c(-0.4971,-0.0946,-0.0244,0.0019,0,-0.0289,-0.0176))
```

Thanks to @jonspring i got the following plot by using this code:

```
df3 <- df %>%
  gather(column, value, -X) %>%
  mutate(group = str_sub(column, end   = 2),
         stat  = str_sub(column, start = 4)) %>%
  select(-column) %>%
  spread(stat, value) %>%
  mutate(combo_label = paste(sep="\n",
                             scales::comma(abs, accuracy = 0.001),
                             scales::percent(per, accuracy = 0.01)))
df3$group = gsub(df3$group,pattern = "CK",replacement = "Cohen's\nKappa")
df3$group = gsub(df3$group,pattern = "JA",replacement = "Jaccard")
df3$group = gsub(df3$group,pattern = "KA",replacement = "Krippen-\ndorff's Alpha")

crg = ifelse(df3$abs< 0,"red","darkgreen")
ggplot(df3, aes(group, abs, label = combo_label)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = group,
                   yend = 0),
                   color = crg) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(vjust = 1.5,
            size = 3,
            lineheight = 1.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.2,0)) +
  facet_grid(~X) +
  labs(x= "Exponent", y = "Wert")
```

[plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdK4Q.png)

When i zoom and have the positive values visible, the labels are written inside the segments. How to place them above / below depending of a positive or negative value?

Zoom with `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.015,0.005))`

[zoomed plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8A15.png)

Thank you for your helping hands.

EDIT: I found the solution already. Like the color changement from red to green i used `ifelse` for the `vjust` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of varieties of ways to display this sort of data with `ggplot`. I highly recommend you check out https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html if you haven't already.

One suggestion you'll find there is that `ggplot` almost always works better if you first convert your data into long (aka "tidy") form. This puts each of the dimensions of the data into its own column, so that you can map the dimension to a visual aesthetic. Here's one way to do that:

```
library(tidyverse)  
df2 <- df %>%
  gather(column, value, -X) %>%
  mutate(group = str_sub(column, end   = 1),
         stat  = str_sub(column, start = 3),
         value_label = if_else(stat == "per", 
                               scales::percent(value, accuracy = 0.1),
                               scales::comma(value, accuracy = 0.01)))
```

Now, the group `a/b/c` is in its own column, as is the type of data `abs/per`, the values are all together in one column, and we also have text labels that suit the type of data.

```
> head(df2)
      X column   value group stat value_label
1   e 1  a_abs -0.3693     a  abs       -0.37
2 e 1,5  a_abs -0.0735     a  abs       -0.07
3   e 2  a_abs -0.0190     a  abs       -0.02
4 e 2,5  a_abs  0.0015     a  abs        0.00
5   e 3  a_abs  0.0000     a  abs        0.00
6 e 3,5  a_abs -0.0224     a  abs       -0.02
```

With that out of the way, it's simpler to try out different combinations of `ggplot` options, which can help highlight different comparisons within the data.

For instance, if you want to compare the different observations within each group, you could put each group into a facet, and each observation along the x axis:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(X, value, label = value_label)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = X, yend = 0), color = "blue") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(vjust = 2, size = 2) +
  facet_grid(stat~group)
```

[image]

Or if you want to highlight how the different groups compared within each observation, you could swap them, like this:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(group, value, label = value_label)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = group, yend = 0), color = "blue") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(vjust = 2, size = 2) +
  facet_grid(stat~X)
```

[image]

You might also try combining the `abs` and `per` data, since they only vary slightly based on the different denominators applicable to each group and/or observation. To do that, it might be simpler to transform the data to keep each `abs` and `per` together:

```
df3 <- df %>%
  gather(column, value, -X) %>%
  mutate(group = str_sub(column, end   = 1),
         stat  = str_sub(column, start = 3)) %>%
  select(-column) %>%
  spread(stat, value) %>%
  mutate(combo_label = paste(sep="\n",
                             scales::comma(abs, accuracy = 0.01),
                             scales::percent(per, accuracy = 0.1)))

ggplot(df3, aes(group, abs, label = combo_label)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = group, yend = 0), color = "blue") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(vjust = 1.5, size = 2, lineheight = 0.8) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.2,0)) +
  facet_grid(~X)
```

[image]

Comment: Whow, the last option sounds very nice. I haven't thought about it to put both variables in one segment only.
btw, as you can see, the "original" observation is number e3 ( = 100%).

Comment: The 3rd example works like a charm for all of my plots, thank you!
one question is left: In other graphs i have more positive values and the labels are written inside of them. How can i put them above the segment? I changed my original question at the end